# UDLD on Nexus 5548 and Nexus 2232

Tags: cisco, switch, spanning-tree, cisco-nexus, udld

Do you know if I turn on UDLD the 5K and 2K will speak UDLD to each other and do you feel this is a benefit to detect any link issues between the 5K and the FEX?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is the Nexus 2000s aren't autonomous switches. They are essentially line cards for the 5ks (or 7ks) and have no independent existence, so you can't run the normal protocols across those fex-fabric links.

To my knowledge, you simply can't run UDLD across a fex-fabric port (there's even a bug, CSCub14112, related to the fact that the UDLD config wasn't being removed from fex-fabric ports in certain conditions on the 5ks), though there may be a similar feature embedded in the proprietary control protocol Cisco uses between the 5k and a FEX.

Comment: I don't know firsthand, and I wouldn't have thought you could set up a FEX with UDLD, but [this document](http://ciscoskills.net/2013/12/01/connecting-fex-5k-to-2k/) seems to indicate that it works with the `feature fex` command.

Comment: I may be missing the bit you're referring to, but all I see about UDLD there is that it is also in the feature list, i.e. you can do "feature fex" and you can do "feature udld" but they don't have any relation to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Any Cisco device which can run UDLD can use it with any other Cisco device which can run UDLD. Enabling UDLD can help prevent STP problems. UDLD must be enabled on both devices to actually work, and you should only enable it on ports which are connected to other devices running UDLD.

A lot of Cisco routers don't have UDLD, and some can log "unknown protocol" on some ports where it is connected.

All in all, it is a good practice to run it where you can.